# Bypass FRP on RCA Tablet

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, frp, rca-voyager

My friend recently purchased a second-hand RCA tablet running Android 6.0 Marshmallow. He came to me to root the device as I have helped him before. Although I have made a mistake this time. I factory reset the device with a Google account **still** on the device. My friend can no longer get in contact with the original owner.

I've looked everywhere and other FRP bypass guides don't work because they have all been patched.

- I managed to bypass setup and open settings, but when pressing on build number **many** times, nothing happened
- I installed an app that would pull up developer options, but it just says that it's not available for this user
- I've factory reset via settings, no luck
- I've force-killed the setup application, home button reappears but doesn't do anything when pressed
- I disabled Google in an attempt to prevent it from asking for an account to be set up, still no luck

I've now run out of ideas, and I'm wondering if anyone can help me.

Comment: I brought the RCA tablet DVD combos from eBay in Feb 2021 and with with same issue with PIN code or needs to enter previous gmail been synced. After spending one day research on how to bypass the FRP code. I found this YouTub video works. Be aware of it needs to have a second language to make it works. https://youtu.be/kqiRw-6HRxQ. Once it works, be sure you uninstall the two software from their server.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

Step 1:

1. First, boot up normally
2. Sign in to a network
3. Allow it to check the connection
4. Then when it asks you to verify your account, press the back button until you get back to networking
5. Choose a different network, type a bunch of random letters/numbers then press show password select it, press assist.
6. Then Google will open
7. Search for Settings
8. From Settings, go to Backup/reset
9. Reset the device
10. Boot normally once again

Step 2:

1. You will be asked to verify again. Turn your device off
2. Reboot into safe mode
3. Then re-bypass into Settings
4. Head to Device info
5. Enable developer mode (press build number 7 times)
6. You can't enable dev mode unless you are in safe mode as there is protection for it
7. Once you have dev mode enabled, you need to turn on USB debugging and OEM unlock

**Whatever you do, don't press the home button. If it works, all of the settings will be unapplied and setup will restart**

Step 3:

1. Now, reboot to recovery (power off, then hold the volume up button while turning the device back on)
2. Next, we need to scroll to `<Reboot to Bootloader>`
3. Press the power button to select it. You will boot into fastboot

Now you will need a PC

1. First, let's check if OEM unlocking is enabled. Run `fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability` from CMD/terminal (you have to have ADB/fastboot installed).

   You will get `(bootloader) unlock_ability = 0` if it isn't enabled. But if it is, you will get `(bootloader) unlock_ability = 1XXXXXXX`
2. If it's enabled, we have to unlock the bootloader (**this will void your warranty**). We have to do this as OEM unlock isn't really enabled. What we've done is made it so the system sees that it's both enabled **and** disabled. This means the only command that will work is `fastboot oem unlock`
3. We're going to run this command. When you do, spam the volume up button to select yes.
4. Now we're almost done. We have to unlock it from flashing too and unlock system critical (in the security update from 2016, the FRP partition was marked as critical and unless we unlock critical partitions, the FRP lock won't ever go away)
5. First, flashing unlock. Run `fastboot flashing unlock`
6. Spam the volume up again
7. Then run `fastboot flashing unlock_critical`
8. Spam volume up again
9. Now close ADB/fastboot on your PC
10. And unplug your device
11. Since security is still enabled, `fastboot reboot` doesn't work. So we have to wait for the device to drain completely.
12. Then charge it a bit and turn it back on. It will wipe the FRP partition alone with all the other ones, except for the `/boot` partition.

FRP is disabled now.

This will work on any Android device with fastboot. Did this from an RCA tablet, so it does.

Comment: Yes it works, tested with rca-rct6873w42mkc. Many thanks to OMG(user)

Comment: What if I I click on a different network after pressing back and input the random letter/numbers. Then show password and select, but all that comes up after it's selected is "Cut, Copy, Paste" no assist. What do I do then.